# Are there any special requires for the use of fstream?

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream, ofstream

I want to use fstream to write and read an array,some bug happened...
The code of write process is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
       float a[4][16] = {
              3.16216,
              5.97973,
             4.18243,
             4.60135,
             2.7027,
             6.96622,
             6.50676,
             4.28378,
             5.43919,
             8.51352,
             5.30405,
             8.10135,
             2.07432,
             7.83784,
             3.67568,
             8,
             5.25197,
             8.83465,
             6.35433,
            6.65354,
        5.01575,
        7.32283,
        6.95276,
        4.50394,
        4.77165,
        8.18898,
        5.43307,
        7.65354,
        4.64567,
        8.03937,
        4.48031,
        7.49606,
        4.13333,
        6.8381,
        4.94286,
        5.09524,
        3.19048,
        6.48571,
        9.17143,
        4.78095,
        4.24762,
        8.30476,
        8.22857,
        7.33333,
        3.27619,
        9.38095,
        2.56191,
        7.44762,
        4.05195,
        6.94805,
        5.12338,
        5.35065,
        3.43507,
        6.71429,
        8.48052,
        3.94805,
        5.88312,
        8.27922,
        7.34416,
        7.81818,
        2.79221,
        8.90909,
        4.25325,
        7.26623 };

    ofstream database("test.db");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        database.write((char *)a[i], sizeof(float) * 16);
    }
    database.close();
}
```

The code of read process is:

```
    float a[4][16] = { 0 };
ifstream database("test.db");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    database.read((char *)a[i], sizeof(float) * 16);
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
        cout << "output: " << a[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
```

some bug happened:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUub6.png)

The last two elements can not be loaded correctly. but, if i change the size of the array , for example ,change a[4][16] to a[4][15], everything will be ok. Can someone give me some advice, Thanks a lot!

Comment: That 2D array is going to be contiguous so you could forget about the loop and just write `4 * 16` items direct.

Comment: You might be running to ASCII/binary problem. When using `ostream::write` and `istream::read`, it is necessary to use binary mode for opening the files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, binary mode works well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `2D` array is *contiguous* and since `sizeof(a)` gives the size of the entire array in bytes, and since `a` is the address of the first element, you can do this:

```
std::cout << "dump out\n";

{
    std::ofstream database("test.db", std::ios::binary);
    database.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(a), sizeof(a));
}

std::cout << "read back\n";

{
    std::ifstream database("test.db", std::ios::binary);
    database.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(a), sizeof(a));
}
```

**Note::** The use of `std::ios::binary` needed on some systems to prevent line-ending conversion (data corruption).

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(a)` should suffice.

Comment: @Swordfish yes, that's better.